# Instead of display Categoryid Categoryname should displayed using node js mongodb

Tags: reactjs, node.js

i am a beginner of nodejs. i am making a inventory management using nodejs with react. what is the problem which i faced is i want shown into the table instead of category id need to shown up category name.what i tried so far i attached below. when the record view on the table  as **N/A**

**Product Model**

```
productname: {
                type:String,
                required: true
        },
        description: {
            type:String,
            required: true
        },
        price:{
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        status:{
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        },
        category: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Category',
            required: true           
        },
        brand: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Brand',
            required: true           
        }
```

**
View Product
**

```
var getDataConntrollerfn = async (req, res) =\> {
try {

    const product = await productModel.find({});
    res.send(product);

} catch (error) {
res.status(400).send(error);
}
};
```

**React Table **

```
 `         ` <td>{product.productname}</td>          
            <td>{product.price}</td>        

            <td>{product.category ? product.category.catname : 'N/A'}</td>`
```

`

Output display as N/A

**Category Model**

```
 catname: {
                type:String,
                required: true
        },
        status:{
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        }
```